# What is the argument's type for a method that takes indefinite nested arrays?

Tags: java

I am trying to build a static method that traverses a nested array of arrays. I would like to set this method argument to accept any number of nested arrays. In other words, this function should be able to operate an array of arrays or an array of array of arrays (for example).

I illustrate here with an example:

```
private static void doStuffWithArrays(someType arrays){
        //Do some stuff
    }
```

What is the right data type to be in place of `someType`?

Comment: You could use `Object[]`. You'll have to examine the array at runtime to see what structure it actually has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Object[]`.

Methods in the JDK that takes an arbitrarily nested array, like [`deepToString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString(java.lang.Object%5B%5D)), do this too.

Since you don't know whether an object in that outermost array is an inner array, you would have to check `getClass().isArray()`:

```
private static void doStuffWithArrays(Object[] outermostArray){
    for (int i = 0 ; i < outermostArray.length ; i++) {
        Object outerElement = outermostArray[i];
        if (outerElement.getClass().isArray()) {
            Object[] innerArray = (Object[])outermostArray[i];
            // ... do things with innerArray
        } else {
            // we reached the innermost level, there are no inner arrays
        }
    }
}
```

If you are dealing with arrays of primitives, however, you would need to check each of the primitive array classes separately, then cast to the correct one.

```
if (outerElement.getClass() == int[].class) {
    int[] innerArray = (int[])outermostArray[i];
    // ... do things with innerArray
} else if (outerElement.getClass() == short[].class) {
    short[] innerArray = (short[])outermostArray[i];
    // ... do things with innerArray
} else if (outerElement.getClass() == long[].class) {
    long[] innerArray = (long[])outermostArray[i];
    // ... do things with innerArray
} else if ... // do this for all the other primitive array types
} else if (outerElement.getClass().isArray()) {
    Object[] innerArray = (Object[])outermostArray[i];
    // ... do things with innerArray
} else {
    // we reached the innermost level, there are no inner arrays
}
```

`deepToString` does this too.

Comment: OP may not understand this so I'll mention it: Java does not have '2D' or '3D' arrays, only 1D arrays; an `int[][] x = new int[1][1];` is a 1D array of int arrays, and `int[]` is a subtype of Object. Hence why `Object[]` covers all deeply nested arrays.

Comment: The snippet of code is not something you should actually copy/paste here, just glean the various API calls you need to make from it: casting it to `Object[]` is going to fail if `outermostArray[i]` is an `int[]` (which is still `.getClass().isArray() == true` - it is an array, just not an array of objects).